# Lyx Missing classes - fresh fedora install

Tags: lyx, hebrew, linuxfedora

I am a new fedora user after using ubuntu and some of its derivatives for the last two years (and a new stackexchange user). I have installed the KDE spin of fedora 24.

I have tried to install lyx with Hebrew articles support, so I have installed texlive, texlive-babel-hebrew and Lyx packages from rpmfusion, and downloaded the culmus source pack from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ivritex/files/culmus-latex/), and applied "make" and "make install" in the terminal.

**The problem:**
When I have opened lyx, I got the following problem:

> "The selected document class Article (Standard Class) requires external files that are not available. The document class can still be used, but the document cannot be compiled until the following prerequisites are installed: *article.cls*"

When looking at the *Document->Settings->Document Class* most of the classes are unavailable, including some of the "main" classes - article, ams article, book etc.

I have tried to use *tools->Reconfigure*, and it didn't help. Also, I have used the "make uninstall" rule to remove the changes made by culmus, removed everything connected to texlive by:

```
sudo dnf remove texlive\*
```

and reinstalled by:

```
sudo dnf install texlive texlive-babel-hebrew lyx
```

and then using the *tools->Reconfigure*, getting the same result. (However, the preferences file wasn't deleted, since I got no "welcome" document after the first time opening lyx).

**Edit:**
I'm now capable of compiling a file, but I can not use the Article layout. I can see only geographical layouts and such. Looking at the relevant directories, I can see the layouts and the classes that suppose to be "missing" or "unavailable".

*- How can I fix the problem with the missing *.cls* files?* **Edit** Lyx still doesn't recognize most of the classes in this directory.

*On ubuntu I use the [install-tl-ubuntu](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu) script, and it resolves the Hebrew stuff, listing the packages starting with **texlive** I got around 3.4 Gigabyte of packages, and I don't want to install all of those, since many aren't relevant at all. (The above-mentioned install-tl-ubuntu script also installs many unnecessary packages and classes, which some can be removed)*

Comment: The classes were working before you installed culmus ?

Comment: Note that for the `install-tl-ubuntu` script you do not have to install all of those packages. See the `--profile` option and the `example.profile` file that is in the git repo.

Comment: First of all, I must thank you @scottkosty for the great script. However, I had problems when using --hebrew flag, and only the full installation worked for me.

Comment: @EladDen, I haven't tried to use it before I have installed culmus. However, after I had uninstalled and then reinstalled the texlive texlive-babel-hebrew and lyx packages (without installing culmus), I also had the problem.

Maybe I there is something I haven't removed, but it doesn't seem to recognize any classes even after that.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is with the lyx install and not the hebrew... do you have the lyx layouts installed ? do you have the cls files ?

Comment: So am I.

Looking at the directory:
/usr/share/lyx/layouts
I can see the layouts (including the Hebrew layouts).

Looking at the directory:
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base
I can see the classes, including the "missing" article.cls class.

I succeeded compiling a file (somehow, can't figure out what happens since yesterday), however I still can't find most of the document layouts, although they appear in the layouts directory.